# Modifying a 3D allocated matrix by passing it to a function in MPI environment

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, mpi, dynamic-memory-allocation

In my code i initialized a 3D matrix in this way in an MPI environment

```
double ***grid=NULL;
grid=(double***)malloc(2 * sizeof(double **));
for(i=0;i<l;i++){
    grid[i] = (double**)malloc(nrow * sizeof(double*));
    for(j=0;j<nrow;j++){
        grid[i][j] = (double*)malloc(ncol*sizeof(double));
    }
}   
inidat(nrow, ncol, &grid[0][0][0]);
```

Where ncol and nrow are command line variables. The function inidat() initialize the problem by taking as imput "grid", the function looks like this:

```
void inidat(int nx, int ny, double *u1){
int ix, iy;
for (ix = 0; ix <= nx-1; ix++){ 
  for (iy = 0; iy <= ny-1; iy++){ 
     *(u1+ix*ny+iy) = (double)(ix * (nx - ix - 1) * iy * (ny - iy - 1));
    }
}
```

The problem is that sometimes i get a segmentation fault and i have no idea why.

Comment: you should always include a [mcve] in your questions. anyway, do not use jagged arrays but allocate your 3D matrix in contiguous memory.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Totally. I always try to minimize separate allocations when possible.

Comment: Make your life easier and allocate 3D array as a pointer to VLA. Just do `double (*grid)[nrow][ncol] = calloc(2, sizeof *grid);`

Comment: also, note the initial malloc has a `2`, but the following loop uses `l`. That won't work if `l > 2`.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach to matrix creation doesn't work. You are not creating a single block of memory but many scattered areas. This does not work with MPI because it assumes that a buffer is a contiguous block.

So you should create your matrix as `double *matrix`, and using an indexing macro

```
#define INDEX(i,j) (i)*n+(j)

matrix[ INDEX(i,j) ]
```

in your code. This is barely harder to code, and much more efficient in performance.